# Decode a byte encoded string via my URL

Tags: php

We have a PHP site on Zend Framework with a backend Postgresql database. Our primary character encoding is UTF-8.

I just checked our error log and found a strange entry. My URL is as follows:
www.mydomain.com/schuhe-für-breite-füsse

however someone (or maybe a bot) has tried to access this URL as follows:
www.mydomain.com/schuhe-f\xc3\xbcr-breite-f\xc3\xbcsse/

It's the first time I've seen something like the above. Two things are happening on my page:
1) The above URL is queried against our CMS. This works fine for some reason, I think Postgresql reaslises it is byte-encoded and then converts it back when tried to find this SEF URL in our database.

2) An Ajax request is made on the page, passing the same SEF URL. This fails. I believe the slashes are causing a problem on Javascript.

To avoid this I want to decode any URL that is encoded like this. However a quick test of the following code did not decode anything for me :(

```
$landing_sef_url = $this->_getParam('landing_sef_url');
$utf8=html_entity_decode($landing_sef_url);
$iso8859=utf8_decode($utf8);
$test3 = html_entity_decode($landing_sef_url, 1, "ISO-8859-1");
$test4 = urldecode($landing_sef_url);

echo utf8_decode("$landing_sef_url");
echo "<br/><br/>";
die($landing_sef_url . " -- $utf8 -- $iso8859 <br/>$test3<br/>$test4");
```

I found the above via various posts online but they all print back the same result - schuhe-f\xc3\xbcr-breite-f\xc3\xbcsse

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method seems to do what you're looking for:

http://li.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php

But if you're just looking to unescape \x## sequences, you could also do this with a fairly simple regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm looking to completely convert those kinds of characters to their correct UTF-8 equivalents. Is there a way I can do this? Or a ready regular expression I can use? I'm not sure of the most efficient way to do this since this is a rare scenario yet still possible. Many thanks.

Comment: It is extremely likely that this will do the trick, in your example you mention `\xc3\xbc`, which is the exact binary representation of ü in UTF-8.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't realise stripslashes() went into this much detail! It did the trick and I went live with the update. Thanks so much!

Comment: well it just treats it as a binary string. So be careful, if I were you I would also make sure that the resulting url is valid UTF-8

Comment: Thanks very much again. I did some tests on normal English URLs and German/French special character URLs and these all seem to work fine now :) Cheers

Comment: Yea, i just mean.. for security.. you will want to validate the resulting string if it's correct UTF-8. Use mine, if you want : https://github.com/evert/sabre-vobject/blob/master/lib/Sabre/VObject/StringUtil.php